# Geodesic deviation in flat space

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose that $x^\mu(t,s)$ represents a family of curves.
Let $v^\mu$ represents the the tangent vector to a curve $x^\mu(t,s_0)$ with $s_0$ fixed that is $v^{\mu}=\partial x^{\mu} / \partial t$  and deviation vector is given by $\xi^{\alpha}=\partial x^{\alpha} / \partial s$.

In the usual derivation of the geodesic deviation equation it is showed that $\xi$ is **lie transposed** through $v$ that is $$L_v\xi=0$$ where $L$ stands for the lie derivative.
To make the discussion more clear let us suppose we are in flat spacetime with  usual Cartesian coordinates $x^0=t,x^1,x^2,x^3$.

We choose  $x^\mu(t,s)=(t,st,0,0)$ and so $v^\mu=(1,s,0,0)$ and $\xi^{\alpha}=(0,t,0,0)$

we have $$L_v\xi=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+s\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}},t\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}} \right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial s}{\partial x^1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$$

So we choose the parameter $s$ for example to $2x^1$ we would have $L_v\xi \ne0$

Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: The fact is that $L_v\xi = [v,\xi]$, not $[\partial_t,\xi]$.

Comment: @Didier at $s=0$ $v=\partial_t$

Comment: But you cannot compute a Lie bracket by fixing the variables as it is not something that depends only on the value of the vector fields at a fixed point.

Comment: @Didier I am confused about your last comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete rewriting of my answer. I insist that the problem is that you are making confusion between the two "$t$" variables, and I suggest anybody reading this to avoid using the same symbol for two completely different coordinates patch.

I will restrict to the two dimensional case as there is nothing to say about the two last variables. You are considering the function
\begin{align}
f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 &\to \mathbb{R}^2 \\
(t,s) & \mapsto (t,st)
\end{align}
This function is, away from the line $\{t=0\}$, a diffeomorphism onto its image: it is injective, and its Jacobian is $t\neq 0$. Use the coordinate system ${x^1,x^2}$ to describe $\mathbb{R}^2$ on the RHS. Then:
\begin{align}
v(t,s)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,s) &= \partial_1|_{f(t,s)} + s \partial_2|_{f(t,s)},\\
\xi(t,s) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(t,s) &= t \partial_2|_{f(t,s)}.
\end{align}

Here is the trick: in terms of the coordinates $(x^1,x^2)$, we have $t(x^1,x^2) = x^1$ and $s(x^1,x^2) = \frac{x^2}{x^1}$. Hence, you can write, away from $\{x^1=0\}$, $v$ and $\xi$ as vector fields on the RHS with:
\begin{align}
v &= \partial_1 + \frac{x^2}{x^1}\partial_2,\\
\xi &= x^1 \partial_2.
\end{align}
Therefore:
\begin{align}
[v,\xi] &= \left[\partial_1 + \frac{x^2}{x^1}\partial_2, x^1\partial_2\right] \\
&= \left[\partial_1,x^1 \partial_2\right] + \left[\frac{x^2}{x^1}\partial_2,x^1\partial_2\right]\\
&= \partial_2 +  \left[\frac{x^2}{x^1}\partial_2,x^1\partial_2\right].
\end{align}
Use the formula $\left[fX,gY\right] =  fg[X,Y] + f \left(X\cdot g\right)Y - g \left(Y\cdot f\right)X$, it follows that:
\begin{align}
\left[\frac{x^2}{x^1}\partial_2,x^1 \partial_2 \right] &= \frac{x^2}{x^1}\cdot x^1 \underbrace{[\partial_2,\partial_2]}_{=0} + \frac{x^2}{x^1}\underbrace{\left( \partial_2 x^1\right)}_{=0}\partial_2 - x^1 \cdot \underbrace{\partial_2\left(\frac{x^2}{x^1} \right)}_{= \frac{1}{x^1}} \partial_2 \\
&= - \partial_2,
\end{align}
and the result follows.

(This is not surprising: $f$ restricted to $\{t\neq 0\}$ being a diffeomorphism onto its image, by naturality of the Lie bracket:
$[v,\xi]=[\partial_tf,\partial_sf] = [f_*\partial_t,f_*\partial_s] = f_*[\partial_t,\partial_s] = f_*(0) = 0.$)

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: See my edit: you just use $t$ for two different variables that are not the same and this bring you to make an error in the computation. This is why, in my opinion, overuse of coordinates is a bad habbit.

Comment: they are the same. I chose  it to be the same

Comment: But this is not possible because the vector field $\partial_t$ is a two dimensional vector field on the LHS and a four dimmensional one on the RHS.

Comment: I did not understand your last comment.

Comment: @amiltonmoreira I completely edited my answer and hope that it will finally answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Away from $t=0$ you can think of $x$ as a regular parametrization of a surface in your 4D space. The vector fields you call $v$ and $\xi$ are just the coordinate vector fields usually called $x_t$ and $x_s$. Their Lie bracket vanishes because $x_{st}=x_{ts}$.